# Is there a way to put react hooks in a function that's not function component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a function that is not a component nor hooks that's callable on speficic event. Let's say i have a simple function that post a data using axios and i want to use navigate after the post is successfull. Here's the example

```
export const authLogin = (email, password) => {
    const config = {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken': Cookies.get('csrftoken')
        }
    }

    let navigate = useNavigate();

    return dispatch => {
        console.log('Masuk ke dalam auth file');
        dispatch(authStart());
        axios.post('/log_in/', {
            email: email,
            password: password
        }, config)
            .then(res => {
                if (res.data.error) {
                    alert(res.data.error)
                    dispatch(authFail(res.data.error))
                }
                else {
                    const token = res.data.key;
                    const expirationDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3600 * 1000);
                    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
                    localStorage.setItem('expirationDate', expirationDate);
                    dispatch(authSuccess(token));
                    dispatch(checkAuthTimeout(3600));
                    alert('login berhasil')
                    navigate("/", { replace: true });
                }

            })
            .catch(err => {
                alert(err);
                dispatch(authFail(err))
            })
    }
}
```

I have an error that says
[image]

but when i try to change the function name with an uppercase letter, another problem occured, how do i resolve this problem?[image]

Comment: It's like it says, can only use hooks in functional components or other hooks... Why don't you make the caller a hook and call it from a functional component? Otherwise, remove all hook calls from your function and use it like a regular function, can't have both :)

Comment: Please create an [mre], especially include the place where the function is called. Note that neither hooks nor components are determined by how they're named, but how they're used.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hook must be attached to a fiber which is **directly** attached to the React component tree. You **CANNOT** use hooks outside the component tree because React can't keep track of them (this is why hooks must always be run in the same order, and can't be conditional, because React keeps track of their state internally).

The only time you can use a hook outside of a component, is from another hook.

In short, you must be able to draw a straight line back from the hook call to React rendering the component tree. If you cannot, then it's an invalid hook call.

**THE SOLUTION**

...in your case - is to simply pass in the `navigate` function to your action as a parameter:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
 
   const navigate = useNavigate();

   const doSomethingHandler = () => {
      dispatch(authLogin(email,password,navigate))
   }

}


const authLogin = (email,password,navigate) => {

    // ...do your action and call the `navigate` parameter
    // when you need to
}
```